# How can you speed up a genoise cake mixing?

Tags: eggs, sponge-cake

I usually make a chocolate Swiss roll.

The first step is to beat 4 eggs together with 115g sugar on a double boiler with warm (tap) water. I use a hand mixer for this, and it takes a long time, plus the machine gets really hot in the end.

My question is if there's a way to speed up the process? I haven't timed it (next time). I don't put the double boiler on a stove, it's just filled with warm water. My mixing bowl is plastic.

Comment: I think some more details might help. What's the recipe and method? Are you beating whole eggs, just whites, or just yolks? What is the result you are trying to achieve with the eggs?

Comment: @GdD As stated, 4 eggs with 115g sugar. Those are whole eggs. I try to achieve a 'ribbon' like [described here](http://baking911.com/quick-guide/how-to-az/eggs-beating-techniques-whole-eggs-and-yolks)

Comment: Does the recipe call for heating the water bath?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that the purpose of the double boiler is to bring the eggs up to room temperature, which isn't going to make that much of a difference. Most recipes would say that the process will take 10 minutes, but you may be able to speed things up marginally:

- Use a bowl that concentrates the eggs in as small an area as possible so your beater blades contact as much eggs as possible per rotation. A narrow, tall bowl is better than a wide, shallow one. If you don't have that then tip the bowl you do have so it all concentrates in one area
- Use fresh eggs, I've found that fresher eggs take air better. It's true for egg whites at least, so I suspect it will be for whole eggs as well
- Let the eggs come up to room temperature before using them, that way you don't need the double boiler setup, which will give you more flexibility when it comes to bowls. If you don't have 20-30 minutes to let the eggs warm naturally then 5 minutes submerged in tepid water will do the same thing

Other than that the only thing I can recommend is to buy a stand mixer or cultivate patience. Preferably both.

Comment: I suspect this is actually a genoise, in which the eggs and sugar are cooked together....

Comment: If it calls for a genoise it's not really a swiss roll, but a genoise roll. Swiss rolls don't use a genoise.

Comment: So many other terms are used loosely, that wouldn't surprise me.  And genoise is well suited for rolled applications.

Comment: +10 for getting the eggs to room temperature before you start.

Comment: Remember, that when you use a double boiler, you don't need to use a full pan of water... is waiting for your water below the double boiler to get hot part of the time lag?

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ, yes, I've changed the title of the question accordingly. Thanks.